# knocking noise sounds like its coming from under my feet!

Tags: chevrolet, noise, knock, cavalier

I have an 03 chevy cavalier. While out driving yesterday it started to make a loud knocking noise. It sounded like it was coming from under drivers feet area. It also got louder with acceleration. Not a mechanic, or much about about cars, any advice would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Needs to be inspected - driveshaft joint possibly, louder and faster with acceleration ?

Comment: Few days ago i had new rotors & brake put in, at that point i realized i needed wheel hub & that bolts connected cv joints were loose, so there wete tightened up. What i think happened was some type of grove was made in cv joint & when bolts were tightened it moved the grove from where it originally was. What do you think?